# Sticking an icon to the left beside an input text box

Tags: html, css

I need your help,

My problem is that I cannot seem to get the input box to properly line up beside my icon. It seems that it wraps itself to the next line and also breaks outside the parent div border?

How can I get the icon to properly line up on the left side of the input box.

Here is a capture of the problem:

[image]

Here is the desired result:

[image]

Here is the HTML and CSS markup in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<style type="text/css">
.field {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 200px;
}
#fileno {
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#icon_search {
    background: #FFF;
    border: 0;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="field">
    <div id="icon_search" style="float: left;"><img alt="search" width="16" height="16" src="glass.png"/></div>
    <input id="fileno" type="text">
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `#fileno` has `width:100%`. There's no room for both the field and the icon. Since you've defined the width of `.field` and `img`, you can also define the width of `#fileno` in pixels: `184px` [200px - 16px].

And, from the code that you gave, the `#icon_search` didn't seem necessary, so I removed it and put `float: left` on `.field img`. If there's another reason for it, it should still work with the width defined in `#fileno`. If that `div` is necessary, let me know and I can put it back in, but, basically it's because `#fileno` was `100%`.

HTML:

```
<div class="field">
    <img alt="search" width="16" height="16" src="glass.png"/>
    <input id="fileno" type="text">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.field {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 200px;
}
#fileno {
    width: 184px;
    border: 0;
}
.field img {
    float: left;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pLgzpuvh/).

Answer (score 0):

you should use % so you can re-use it by simple change the `width` of the parent in this case `.field`

```css
.field {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
#fileno {
  border: 0;
  width: 90%;
}
#icon_search {
  background: #FFF;
  height: 20px;
  width: 10%;
}
#icon_search img{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <div id="icon_search" style="float: left;">
    <img alt="search" width="16" height="16" src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.clker.com%2Fcliparts%2F0%2F1%2FS%2F1%2Fl%2FW%2Fsearch-icon-hi.png&f=1" />
  </div>
  <input id="fileno" type="text" placeholder="search">
</div>
```